# Operator overloading not working

Tags: lua

While reading **Programming in Lua**, I tried this example given in the book for operator overloading

```
Set = {}

mt = {}
mt.__add = Set.union

--create a new set with the values of the given list
function Set.new (l) 
    local set = {}
    setmetatable (set, mt)
    for _, v in ipairs (l) do 
        set [v] = true
    end
    return set
end 

function Set.union (a, b)
    local result = Set.new {}
    for k in pairs (a) do result [k] = true end
    for k in pairs (b) do result [k] = true end
    return result
end

function Set.intersection (a, b)
    local result = Set.new {}
    for k in pairs (a) do result [k] = b[k] end
    return result
end

function Set.tostring (set)
    local l = {}
    for e in pairs (set) do
        l[#l + 1] = e
    end
    return "{" .. table.concat (l, ", ") .. "}"
end 

function Set.print (s)
    print (Set.tostring (s))
end 

s1 = Set.new {10, 20, 30, 50}
s2 = Set.new {30, 1}

Set.print (s1)
Set.print (s2)

s3 = s1 + s2
Set.print (s3)
```

But with the latest `lua for windows` I am getting the following error

```
lua: C:\meta.lua:47: attempt to perform arithmetic on global 's1' (a table value)
stack traceback:
    C:\meta.lua:47: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
{30, 10, 20, 50}
{1, 30}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are making this assignment too early:

```
mt.__add = Set.union
```

because `Set.union` is not initialized yet.

Move this below `Set.union` and it will work.

For the same reason, if you assign `mt.__mul`, this should be below `Set.intersection`

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `mt` as a suitable metatable:

```
mt = { __add = Set.union, __mul = Set.intersection, __tostring = Set.tostring }
```

Comment: Apologies, I missed the code part where I defined the meta table

Comment: This answer no longer makes sense, because of the edit to the question